# Nested Form Cant Connect With Input?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nested, angular-reactive-forms

i have this component :

```
  shelveForm = this.fb.group({
    description_shelve:['input1',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]],
    id_shelve: ['input2',[Validators.required,WhiteSpaceValidator.cannotContainSpace,Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]],
    war_id:this.fb.group({
      id_warehouse: ['input3']
    })
  })
```

my html:

```
<form [formGroup]="shelveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

{{shelveForm.value | json }}


    <!-- input 1  -->

      <input id="id_shelve" type="text"  formControlName="id_shelve">

    <!-- input 2-->
      <input id="description" type="text"  formControlName="description_shelve">

    <!-- input 3  -->
      <input id="description_war_id" type="text"  formControlName="id_warehouse">

</form>
```

The json i get is:

```
 { 
 "description_shelve": "input1",
 "id_shelve": "input2",
 "war_id": { 
 "id_warehouse": "input3" 
 } 
}
```

*When I type at the input 1 and 2 the values can change, if I type "banana" at input one, the input one becomes banana, ex. "description_shelve: "banana"*, but when I type at input3 the value remains the same, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i find the problem , if someone was the same problem you need to put :

```
  <div class="p-field" formGroupName="war_id">
  <div>
    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="id_warehouse"
    [class.is-invalid]="shelveForm.get('description_shelve').invalid && shelveForm.get('description_shelve').touched"/>
  </div>
</div>
```